# Using DPDK Kernel NIC Interface in a virtualized environment

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, dpdk

I'm going to develop a [DPDK](http://www.dpdk.org/) Linux application on a laptop, but the laptop's hardware is not supported by DPDK. Furtunately, DPDK [supports](http://www.dpdk.org/doc/nics) paravirtualized devices including [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)'s `virtio-net`.

So I'm trying to configure a QEMU guest for running the [Kernel NIC Interface(KNI)](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/sample_app_ug/kernel_nic_interface.html) on a `virtio-net-pci` device. The problem is that the KNI sample application doesn't accept the `virtio-net-pci` driver.

**QEMU command**

```
exec qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm \
  -cpu host -smp 2 \
  -vga std \
  -mem-prealloc -mem-path /dev/hugepages \
  -drive file=GentooVM.img,if=virtio \
  -netdev user,id=vmnic,hostname=gentoo \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vmnic \
  -m 1024M \
  -monitor stdio \
  -name "Gentoo VM"
```

**Running the KNI sample application in the guest**

```
sudo ./examples/kni/build/app/kni -c 0x3 -n 4 -- \
-P -p 0x1 --config="(0,0,1)"

EAL: Detected lcore 0 as core 0 on socket 0
EAL: Detected lcore 1 as core 0 on socket 0
EAL: Support maximum 128 logical core(s) by configuration.
EAL: Detected 2 lcore(s)
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL:   IOMMU type 1 (Type 1) is supported
EAL:   IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU) is not supported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Setting up physically contiguous memory...
...
EAL: WARNING: cpu flags constant_tsc=yes nonstop_tsc=no -> using
unreliable clock cycles !
EAL: Master lcore 0 is ready (tid=657d58c0;cpuset=[0])
PMD: rte_igbvf_pmd_init():  >>
EAL: lcore 1 is ready (tid=305ff700;cpuset=[1])
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:03.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 1af4:1000 rte_virtio_pmd
EAL:   Not managed by a supported kernel driver(0), skipped
PMD: virtio_read_caps(): failed to map pci device!
PMD: vtpci_init(): trying with legacy virtio pci.
Segmentation fault
```

**Output of `lspci` command in the guest**

```
...
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio network device
```

I've noticed that [`pci_scan_one()`](http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_pci.c?id=v16.04#n256) function sets `dev->kdrv = RTE_KDRV_NONE`, while the driver is detected as `virtio-pci` (from `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.0/driver`).

**TAP networking**

The same issue persists with TAP networking. On the host, I've configured a bridge from Wi-Fi interface, and connected it to a TAP interface:

```bash
wifi_iface=wlp3s0
br_iface=br0
br_network='172.20.0.1/16'
br_dhcp_range='172.20.0.2,172.20.255.254'
tap_iface=tap0
user=ruslan

ip link add name $br_iface type bridge
ip addr add "$br_network" dev $br_iface
ip link set $br_iface up
dnsmasq --interface=$br_iface --bind-interfaces \
  --dhcp-range=$br_dhcp_range

modprobe tun
chmod 0666 /dev/net/tun

ip tuntap add dev $tap_iface mode tap user "$user"
ip link set $tap_iface up promisc on
ip link set $tap_iface master $br_iface

sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $wifi_iface -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $tap_iface -o $wifi_iface -j ACCEPT
```

QEMU command:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm \
  -cpu host -smp 2 \
  -vga std \
  -mem-prealloc -mem-path /dev/hugepages \
  -drive file=GentooVM.img,if=virtio \
  -netdev tap,id=vm1_p1,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no,vhost=on \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vm1_p1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3,ioeventfd=on \
  -m 1024M \
  -monitor stdio \
  -name "Gentoo VM" \
  $@
```

`ifconfig` output in the guest:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.196.253  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        inet6 fe80::59c1:f175:aeb3:433  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:12:34:56  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9  bytes 1039 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21  bytes 1802 (1.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The following command fails the same way as in the case of "user" networking above:

```
sudo ./examples/kni/build/app/kni -c 0x3 -n 4 -- \
-P -p 0x1 --config="(0,0,1)"
...
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:03.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 1af4:1000 rte_virtio_pmd
EAL:   Not managed by a supported kernel driver(0), skipped
PMD: virtio_read_caps(): failed to map pci device!
PMD: vtpci_init(): trying with legacy virtio pci.
```

**The question**

Is it even possible to run *KNI* with `virtio-net-pci` device?

If it's impossible, are there other options to develop a *DPDK KNI* application in a virtualized environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`virtio_read_caps()` fails to map the PCI device because DPDK requires [binding network ports](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html?highlight=binding%20network%20port#linux-gsg-binding-kernel) to one of the following kernel modules:

- `uio_pci_generic`,
- `igb_uio`,
- `vfio-pci`:

> As of release 1.4, DPDK applications no longer automatically unbind
>   all supported network ports from the kernel driver in use. Instead,
>   all ports that are to be used by an DPDK application must be bound to
>   the `uio_pci_generic`, `igb_uio` or `vfio-pci` module before the application
>   is run. Any network ports under Linux* control will be ignored by the
>   DPDK poll-mode drivers and cannot be used by the application.

Thus, before running a DPDK KNI application, we should

1. Load at least one of the supported I/O kernel modules(`uio_pci_generic`, `igb_uio` or `vfio-pci`)
2. Load `$RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET/kmod/rte_kni.ko`
3. Bind the network ports to the kernel modules by means of `$RTE_SDK/tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py` script.

For example:

```
$ sudo insmod $RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET/kmod/igb_uio.ko
$ sudo insmod $RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET/kmod/rte_kni.ko
# Obtain ID of the network port
$ python2 $RTE_SDK/tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py --status
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:00:03.0 'Virtio network device' drv=igb_uio unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic
$ sudo python2 $RTE_SDK/tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py --bind=igb_uio 0000:00:03.0
```

where

- `$RTE_SDK` - Points to the DPDK installation directory.
- `$RTE_TARGET` - Points to the DPDK target environment directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure `-netdev user` is incompatible with what you want because it's passing TCP data instead of whole ethernet frames. According to http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking

> User Networking is implemented using "slirp", which provides a full TCP/IP stack within QEMU and uses that stack to implement a virtual NAT'd network.

You want your options to be more like what is specified in http://www.dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/virtio.html

```
-netdev tap,id=vm1_p1,ifname=tap0,script=no,vhost=on
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vm1_p1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3,ioeventfd=on
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue persists with TAP networking as well. I've added 'TAP networking' to the question. Thanks.